# SQL Alchemy: query(<Table>).filter(<Table.element.match(arg)>) does not work properly

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

So I have this filter statement:
`x = self.session.query(URL).filter(URL.long_url.match(longurl))`

`URL Table`

```
from base import Base
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Boolean, Integer


class URL(Base):
    __tablename__ = "urls"

    short_url = Column(String(256), primary_key=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    long_url = Column(String(256), nullable=False, unique=True)
    time = Column(String(256), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, short_url, long_url, time):
        self.short_url = short_url
        self.long_url = long_url
        self.time = time
```

I am just trying to run to find a table row where the match is true.

When the above statement is run I should get a URL object for x.

Instead, I get a Query object indicating that my filter could not find a row with the matching `long_url`.

---

What is wrong with my statement for it to be returning a Query object?

Comment: You need to execute the query, for example calling `.all()` on it will return a list of matching rows.

Comment: @snakecharmerb My understanding of how query worked, was that it would execute automatically on call....so why does it need .all() or .first()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment from @snakecharmerb mentioned, the statement needs to be executed for it returns something more than just a query object.

Adding `.all() or .first()` executes the query and returns either a list of matching objects or just the first matching object, respectively.

But even doing that will not be enough to actually make this statement run without errors, as the current statement throws an Operational Error.

For my purposes, just replacing the `.match()` with a `==` or `is` worked perfectly.

So the new statement became: `x = self.session.query(URL).filter(URL.long_url == longurl).first()`